# How to only select count duplicate data that appears more than once and count each row only once?

Tags: mysql, count

I want to count returning visitors for a given date range. Every `ipAddress` appearing more than once should be calculated as a returning visitor. How can this be done?

Table

```
ipAddress       | last_update
416.246.227.151 | 2020-11-11 19:29:45
416.246.227.151 | 2020-11-11 20:29:45
173.252.127.119 | 2020-11-11 21:29:45
816.246.227.151 | 2020-11-13 13:53:16
816.246.227.151 | 2020-11-13 15:53:16
816.246.227.151 | 2020-11-13 19:53:16
373.252.127.119 | 2020-11-13 22:53:16
673.252.127.119 | 2020-11-13 20:53:16
```

Query

```
SELECT last_update, COUNT(ipAddress) as returningVisitor 
FROM geolocation 
WHERE last_update BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-12-01' 
GROUP BY date(last_update)
HAVING (returningVisitor>1)
```

Result

```
last_update         | returningVisitor
2020-11-11 19:29:45 | 3
2020-11-13 19:53:16 | 5
```

Desired result

```
last_update         | returningVisitor
2020-11-11 19:29:45 | 1
2020-11-13 19:53:16 | 1
```

In reality, the result should be 1 returningVisitor for both dates.
I have tried with `COUNT(DISTINCT ipAddress)` and the result is still not good.

Comment: You didn't ask a very complete question, because there is no sample data.  Can you add that too?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: updated with table information for easier understanding.

Comment: It's still not clear what your criteria are. "How many addresses had more than 1 visit within this date range" is easily done with count on a subquery, but your "desired result" has a datetime column, it's unclear where that's meant to come from.

Comment: @hobbs: I dont know how much clearer it can be. I need to display returning visitors per date by counting duplicate ipAddress. If an ipAddress appears more than once in a day, well that's a returning visitor. We count it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try handling this via a two-tiered aggregation.  First, aggregate by date and IP address, to generate a visit count for each date/IP, and then restrict to only repeat visits on each date.  Next, aggregate that result by date alone and count the number of repeat visitors, from all IP addresses.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DATE(last_update) AS last_update, ipAddress
    FROM geolocation
    WHERE last_update >= '2020-11-01' AND last_update < '2020-12-01' 
    GROUP BY DATE(last_update), ipAddress
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT last_update, COUNT(*) AS returningVisitor
FROM cte
GROUP BY last_update;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo